# why PBI report link open from PowerPoint does not go to PBI report

Tags: powerbi, powerpoint

I am preparing a PowerPoint presentation and include a link for users to go to my PBI report directly, however, when I test to open the link from PowerPoint, it doesn't go to my report, it goes to the Microsoft PBI site.  But if I copy and paste the same url to the browser, it goes to my report.   What did I do wrong?  It's the same link address, but doesn't open correctly when click the url from PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Pls, refer to below link for the workaround. Adding `&noSignupCheck=1` to end of the URL.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-Dashboard-URL-link-defaulting-to-recently-viewed-items/m-p/312689

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).